# Cached files being retrieved in subsequent iterations (when using cache manager) in Jmeter

Tags: performance, caching, server, jmeter, request

as I know, in order to make the JMeter only hits the server for first time, and for second iterations to not hitting the server and make use of cached files made in first iteration, we have to create "HTTP Cache Manager".

But the issue for me is even when I create HTTP Cache Manager, the cached files is being retrieved for each iteration !, and by the way, I am not selected the option "Clear Cache each Iteration "

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTQwY.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSWe7.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Q56Q.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIcq2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxxGU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Up to certain extent it works, you see that 1st request generated 19 sub-results and 2nd request produced only 5 so 14 items were returned from the cache.

You can temporarily enable "Functional Test Mode" in Test Plan to see what requests are being sent

[image]

It might be the case they're either [redirects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) or items which have [`no-store` directive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) hence JMeter doesn't put them into the cache.

Also consider ticking `Parallel downloads` box as this is what real browsers do, in your setup embedded resources are being retrieved sequentially which means that you're generating different network footprint and response times will be larger

[image]

More information: [Web Testing with JMeter: How To Properly Handle Embedded Resources in HTML Responses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter)

Comment: Dear Dmitri, the number of sub results generated is like the former request, 19, but the image doesn't show all the page content.